# Método Router.go() de Iron Router no funciona bien con Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Tengo un mistero con Meteor (version 1.1.0.3) y Iron Router (iron:router@1.0.9).

Estoy haciendo un botón `descartar cambios` en Meteor.

Básicamente, si se pulsa el botón cojo el `_id` del documento que se está ofreciendo por pantalla y redirijo a la misma ruta, pasando el `_id`.

La función que tengo asociada a la ruta busca el documento en la colección adecuada y rederiza la plantilla. Básicamente, quiero machacar todo lo que ya tuviese en mi formulario con el documento de la colección (forzar un "reload").

La funcionalidad de renderizar plantillas funciona bien. Si tecleo a mano una ruta en el navegador todo va perfectamente. Incluso ya estaba usando `Router.go()` con éxito en otras partes de mi programa, de la forma

```
Template.feedbackReport.events({
  "click #seeFeedbackReport" : function(){
    Router.go("/feedbackReview/"+this._id);
  }
});
```

para ir a una ruta. Sin embargo, trato de repetir lo mismo ahora en esta funcionalidad (en una plantilla distinta) y `Router.go()` me ignora completamente.

Se hace la llamada también desde un evento (otro 'click', y se usa también el ID del botón), así que el código es básicamente "corta y pega".

Uso directamente el `_path_`, no tengo nombres para las rutas ni nada que me obligase a poner algo distinto en cada llamada (como sugiere en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32481267/3961519) a una pregunta similar).

Así que no consigo entender la razón de que en algunas partes de mi programa pueda hacer `Router.go()` y en otras la llamada no haga nada.

Sé que `_meteor_` es una "opinionated tool", pero no creo que la manera en la que la plataforma esté reconstruyendo mis `.js` tenga nada que ver con este comportamiento.

**Otra cosa rara:** desde mi nuevo botón me ignora esas llamadas a `Router.go()` (a diferencia de lo que hace para otros eventos iguales), pero si en este botón nuevo pongo la llamada a `Router.go` en el callback de un `_Meteor.call_` entonces `Router.go()` se ejecuta correctamente.

Estoy ya falto de ideas para depurar este comportamiento.

Alguien con experiencia con `IronRouter` y `Meteor` tiene idea de porqué desde unas partes del código `Router.go()` funciona sin problemas y en otras no hace nada?

Answer (score 1):

Hola tal vez esto te sirva

```
Template.feedbackReport.events({
  "click #seeFeedbackReport" : function(){
    Router.go('nameRoute', {id: this._id});
  }
});
```

Comment: Si agregas un poco de descripción a tu respuesta, podrias mejorarla mucho ;)

Comment: Gracias amigo :)

Answer (score 0):

Primero, cuando Iron Router no detecta ningún cambio no actualiza la página y segundo cuando invocas `this` en ese contexto te devuelve el equivalente a `window`.

Para seria mejor hacer un `form.reset()` o un `window.reload()`

Es lo recomendable es que uses `Template.instance().data._id` o `template.data._id`

```
Template.feedbackReport.events({
  "click #seeFeedbackReport" : function( event, template ){
    Router.go("/feedbackReview/" + template.data._id);
  }
});
```